# SoundCloud in Windows 8 app Web broker

Tags: windows-8, soundcloud, webbroker

SoundCloud api doesnot allow to login from Windows 8 Javascript Web broker. I was using Windows 8 any service web broker example

Comment: could you show the code you used for initiating logging in? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to connect a Windows store app using the [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR227025) class, however this was written in C#, but hopefully it can be of assistance:

```
WebAuthenticationResult war = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);
```

startUri is the call to the /connect endpoint and endUri is your callback uri.

You can then process the response and call the /oauth2/token endpoint to get an access token:

```
switch (war.ResponseStatus)
{
    case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
    {
        string response = war.ResponseData;
        string[] responseSplit = response.Split('=');
        string authCode = responseSplit[1];
        // call /oauth2/token with the authorisation code...
        break;
     }
     case WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel:
     {
         OutputMessage(war.ResponseStatus.ToString());
         break;
     }
     case WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp:
     {
         OutputMessage(war.ResponseStatus.ToString());
         break;
     }
}
```

Hopefully you can read this across into JavaScript.

All the best!